# When dropping rows based on str.contains how do I leave in the rows where cells are blank

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop rows based on certain text in certain columns but those columns also contain a lot of blanks and I don't want to drop those rows.

I have the following code but it is not working.

```
DF=DF[~DF['CONTRACT TERM SET NAME'].str.endswith("Tier 2")==True]
DF=DF[~DF['REBATE TERM SET NAME'].str.endswith("Tier 2")==True]
DF=DF[~DF['REBATE TERM SET NAME'].str.contains(" FOP")==True]
DF=DF[~DF['REBATE TERM SET NAME'].str.contains("Tier 3")==True]
DF=DF[~DF['CONTRACT TERM SET NAME'].str.contains("Healthcare Only")==True]
DF=DF[~DF['CONTRACT TERM SET NAME'].str.contains("COCA COLA NORTH AMERICA")==True]
DF=DF[DF['DISTRIBUTOR DIN'].str.contains("NaN")==False]
```

I have also tried the code below which did not work either

```
DF=DF[~DF['CONTRACT TERM SET NAME'].str.endswith("Tier 2",na=False)]
```

Both of these dropped an extra 20k rows that I need, just because the cells in 'CONTRACT TERM SET NAME' or 'REBATE TERM SET NAME' were blank

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can find the "blank" entries with ```pd.isnull(DF)```

Comment: Sorry I am new to python (only been using 2 months now) so not sure that your answer helps.  I don't want to find the blank entries I want them not to be dropped.  When running my code to drop rows based on a string in column it is also dropping any row that is blank but I want to keep those rows

Comment: can you just add another condition for blank cells? For pandas, put each condition in parentheses and separate them with a pipe `|` to do or.

Comment: So I tried using the pipe to add 'NaN'==False but got this error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'bool' and 'str'

Comment: Don't forget operator precedence, use parentheses. Also `~DF['CONTRACT TERM SET NAME'].str.endswith("Tier 2")==True` doesn't make sense. `DF['CONTRACT TERM SET NAME'].str.endswith("Tier 2")` already returns booleans, so `~DF['CONTRACT TERM SET NAME'].str.endswith("Tier 2")` is sufficient

Comment: Yes I had it that way but it is still removing the rows where that field is blank so some googling suggested add the ==True to keep it from removing the rows where it encountered an empty cell

Comment: Looks like you need to chain `and/or` conditions - have you chcked out `np.select` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the isna() function to keep missing values. Here is a section from the pandas docs that documents its usage [ [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) ]

If you want to keep the same syntax that you have been using, here is one possible solution:

```
DF = DF[DF['CONTRACT TERM SET NAME'].isna() | ~DF['CONTRACT TERM SET NAME'].str.endswith("Tier 2")]
```

Comment: Well I tried that but itt ended up just deleting all rows in the database